# Mongo profiler output: what is the "command" operation?

Tags: mongodb, profiling, graylog2

We have a mongo profiler generating documents with operation type "command", e.g.

```
command db.collection [time]
```

(This is truncated output from the graylog mongo plugin)

What does the "command" type represent? What kind of internal mongo operations does it correspond to?

---

There doesn't seem to be anything specific in the [reference manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/database-profiler/) for this other than:

> system.profile.command
>
> The command operation. If the command document exceeds 50 kilobytes, the value is a string summary of the object. If the string summary exceeds 50 kilobytes, the string summary is truncated, denoted with an ellipsis (...) at the end of the string.

I think this is for describing the original command itself though, not an operation type.

Comment: Does it always say "command", even for simple `find` or `insert` queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following MongoDB operatons are treated as command in profiler::

```
 count     
 findAndModify     
 aggregate
```

`

Comment: Citation needed